# Base and structure of wormhole formation

Tags: cosmology

the symbols $r$ and $r_ 0$ (minimum value of $r$) in wormholes structure are given as non dimensional quantities. What reference radius are these quantities defined relative to?

Comment: Where have you read these symbols? We need some context.

Comment: In the wormhole logarithmic shape function as well as the redshift function